# Auto refresh django form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have these codes in my django form. It can display datas that I wanted and can delete it. However, after deleting, I must reload the page so that I can see the data that I have deleted gone. I tried django-fresh but web server error occured. How can the django form auto refresh after deleting? Can give me some examples?

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<form>  
<h1><label for="keywords"> Keywords:</label></h1>
<br>
{% for key in keywords %}
<li>
{{ key.keywords }} <a href="/delete/one/{{key.id}}">delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</li>
<br><br>
{% endfor %}
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: what does the `"/delete/one/{{key.id}}"` view do?

Comment: Could you give a more full example, perhaps the backend django code? Presumably you're not removing the `<li>` elements from the DOM when you click the `<a>` element. So it's removed upon page refresh, but not in an interactive manner. I guess that's what [django-fresh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fresh/1.0.5) is supposed to do. Did you make sure to `import os` in your python code?

Answer (score 0):

Django-fresh will only refresh the page when files in your project change. It's not intended to be used to reset forms or do anything like that in a production setting.

From the docs at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fresh/1.0.5:

> django-fresh will auto-refresh your browser whenever you update to any of the
>   files in your project. Very useful for development, not intended for
>   production!

Django's built-in server won't restart when changes to static files or templates are made, only to Python files. Django-fresh fills that gap.

To reset the form after a post, you would need to re-render your view, passing in any new keyword instances, should they exist. If there are no keywords to delete, I would recommend not rendering the form in the first place.

If you're doing your form submission via ajax, you would need to re-render the form and replace that portion of the HTML in your page.